# How to get all the records between two dates from sqlite database in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-database, sqflite

I am trying to develop an app in which users can save their transactions and related information like transaction date, amount, category, etc. All these fields are stored in an SQLite database using **sqflite plugin**. In that, I want to implement a viewing option in which users can see their transactions but between two dates.
I have made the following function for getting the data from the database:

```
Future<List<expense>> getExpenseDateWise() async {
final db = await database;
var expenses = await db
    .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= ? AND DATE(DATETIME) <= ?',
['$FromDate','$ToDate']); // <----- FromDate and ToDate are two DateTime variables which I am saving from a form

List<expense> expenseList = List<expense>();
expenses.forEach((currentExpense) {
  expense expenses = expense.fromMap(currentExpense);

  expenseList.add(expenses);
});
return expenseList;
}
```

I have checked the query with darabase inspector in android studio, it is working.
And then to display I have implemented the following code:

```
class _dateWiseViewState extends State<dateWiseView> {
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 DatabaseProvider.db.getExpenseDateWise().then(
      (expenseList) {
    BlocProvider.of<ExpenseBloc>(context).add(SetDates(expenseList));
  },);}
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String finalFrom = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(widget.fromDate);
String finalTo = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(widget.toDate);
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("$finalFrom - $finalTo"),
  ),
  body: Container(
      child: BlocConsumer<ExpenseBloc, List<expense>>(
          builder: (context, expenseList) {
            return ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  expense expensess = expenseList[index];
                  return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          border: Border.all(width: 2,color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Text(
                              expensess.name
                                  .substring(0, 1)
                                  .toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            expensess.name ?? "Title",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            "Amount: ${expensess.amount.toString()}"
                                "\nDate: ${expensess.pickedDate}\n"
                            ,style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                          }
                      )
                  );
                },
              itemCount: expenseList.length,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(color: Colors.black),
                );
          },
        listener: (BuildContext context, expenseList) {},
       ),),);}
    }
```

I expected this code to work fine, but it does return the list but it also includes transactions from other months, please look carefully in the image below **(Focus on the dates)**:
[image: view]

I have attached the following image as well that the query is working with database inspector:
[image: databaseInspector]

Look into the database inspector and the page database inspector with the same query is showing 2 entries while the page is showing 4 entries.
I don't know why is it happening please help me with it.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: So that you now. Querying for a date object within sql lite is not supported. You can save your DateTime via an INTEGER (DateTime.milliSecondsSinceEpoch) and then query for it within your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Future<List> getRangeData(String fromDate, String toDate) async{
   var dbClient = await db;
   var result = await dbClient
        .rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName where $columnDate >= '2021-01-01' and 
    $columnDate <= '2022-10-10' ");
   return result.toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro did you check whether your query doing its job correctly?

Comment: Yeah I checked the raw query in database inspector